# How pop to root page, when return to app after power button pressed, without app showing blank screen?

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm developing a .NET Maui application for an Android tablet. When the power button is pressed the application have to show the root/main page.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new InitialPage());
    }

    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
    {
        Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);

        window.Stopped += Window_Stopped;
        window.Resumed += Window_Resumed;

        return window;
    }

    private void Window_Resumed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Window_Stopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        //Inspecting the navstack shows that the PopToRoot worked
        //but on the device the screen got blank
    }
}
```

**Before PopToRootAsync**
[image: Before the PopToRootAsync]

**After the PopToRootAsync**
[image]

The problem is that the device screen got blank when I resume it (power button again) if the PopToRootAsync in the Window_Stopped method runs.

Comment: What happens if you remove that logic from Window_Stopped, then add to Window_Resumed: `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => MainPage.Navigation.PopToRootAsync() );` The idea is to do the pop in a way that should be able to correctly re-display the root page. If this doesn't work after power-button, then will need code to do a more thorough restart of app. I don't know that code off the top of my head. Its more involved; must determine whether this is "first start" of app, or a restart after stopped.

Comment: Unfortunately PopToRoot on MainThread didn't work either. I'll try to go futher on the second option, thanks.